# Database shows up empty but log in was successful

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am creating a Database where if a user clicks on the Register, their information such as username, email and password will be recorded into the database.

The problem however is that, whenever I open up the database, it is always empty!
Even though the app allows me to log in with an account I just created.

I managed to see results in the database twice, but have no idea how I did it.
But at most times it just opens up with the tables but no results

```
package com.example.finalyearproject;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class userDatabase
extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public static String DATABASE_NAME = "User.db";
public static int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "user_table";
public static final String COL_ID = "ID";
public static final String COL_USERNAME = "USERNAME";
public static final String COL_EMAIL = "EMAIL";
public static final String COL_PASSWORD = "PASSWORD";

public userDatabase(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME +"(" +
            COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            COL_USERNAME + " text, " +
            COL_PASSWORD + " text, " +
            COL_EMAIL + " text " +
            ")";
    db.execSQL(sql);
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public boolean create (Account account) {
    boolean result = true;
    try
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_USERNAME, account.getUsername());
        contentValues.put(COL_EMAIL, account.getEmail());
        contentValues.put(COL_PASSWORD, account.getPassword());
        result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues) > 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        result = false;
    }
    return result;
}

public Account login(String username, String password) {
    Account account = null;
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME +
                " where username = ? and password = ?",
                new String[]{username, password});

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            account = new Account();
            account.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            account.setUsername(cursor.getString(1));
            account.setEmail(cursor.getString(2));
            account.setPassword(cursor.getString(3));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        account = null;
    }
    return account;
}

public Account checkUsername(String username) {
    Account account = null;
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME +
                        " where username = ?",
                new String[]{username});

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            account = new Account();
            account.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            account.setUsername(cursor.getString(1));
            account.setEmail(cursor.getString(2));
            account.setPassword(cursor.getString(3));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        account = null;
    }
        return account;
}
```

}

And here is my Signup Form's Code

```
    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;

public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

userDatabase myDb;

private EditText editUser, editPassword, editEmail, editCpassword;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
    setTitle("Sign Up");
    myDb = new userDatabase(this);
    editUser = findViewById(R.id.editSignUpUser);
    editPassword = findViewById(R.id.editSignUpPassword);
    editEmail = findViewById(R.id.editSignUpEmail);
    editCpassword = findViewById(R.id.editConfirmpassword);
    Button buttonRegister = findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(SignUp.this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.buttonRegister) {
        try {
            userDatabase userDatabase = new userDatabase(getApplicationContext());
            Account account = new Account();
            account.setEmail(editEmail.getText().toString());
            account.setPassword(editPassword.getText().toString());
            account.setUsername(editUser.getText().toString());
            Account temp = userDatabase.checkUsername(editUser.getText().toString());

            if (temp == null) {
                if (userDatabase.create(account)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, MainActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                    builder.setTitle("Error");
                    builder.setMessage("Can not Create");
                    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                            dialogInterface.cancel();
                        }
                    });
                    builder.show();
                }
            } else {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
                builder.setTitle("Error");
                builder.setMessage("Username Exists");
                builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                        dialogInterface.cancel();
                    }
                });
                builder.show();

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
            builder.setTitle("Error");
            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    }
}
```

}

And Here is my MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements View.OnClickListener {


private EditText editLoginUsername;
private EditText editLoginPassword;
private Button ButtonLectureLogin;
private Button ButtonStudentLogin;
private Button ButtonSignUp;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editLoginUsername = findViewById(R.id.editLoginUser);
    editLoginPassword = findViewById(R.id.editLoginPassword);

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.buttonStudentLogin);
    button.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    button = findViewById(R.id.buttonLecturerLogin);
    button.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);
    button = findViewById(R.id.buttonSignUp);
    button.setOnClickListener(MainActivity.this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId()==R.id.buttonSignUp) {
        Intent intent  = new Intent(
                MainActivity.this,
                SignUp.class);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    else if (v.getId()==R.id.buttonLecturerLogin) {
        userDatabase userDatabase = new userDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        String username = editLoginUsername.getText().toString();
        String password = editLoginPassword.getText().toString();
        Account account = userDatabase.login(username, password);

        if (account == null) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
            builder.setTitle("Error");
            builder.setMessage("Invalid Account");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Lecturer.class);
            intent.putExtra("Account", account);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    else if (v.getId()==R.id.buttonStudentLogin) {
        //code for when button is pressed, checks database then redirects accordingly
    }

}
```

}

It is not fully complete yet as i am trying to figure out how to get my database working before i continue

Comment: don't you need to commit after making a transaction?

Comment: i'm sorry, i don't really understand by what you meant with commit after making a transaction :S

Comment: also what does this code you posted mean? there is no sign of updating database, this code is just creation and deletion of tables

Comment: isn't onUpgrade the same as updating of the database?

Comment: Can you log out the return value of `create()`? Just to ensure it is returning `true`. Can you also store the value of `db.insert()` in an `int` to ensure it's returning `1`?

Comment: uh... how do i do that? :S

Comment: System.out.println for example.. also, if the onUpgrade method is executed after an insert (I assumed that from your posts), then the table is always dropped and then recreated after you make an insert

Comment: something like boolean if insert = true , print something?

Comment: for example. or just assert the value of create into some variable and print the value

Comment: do you validating the user while login? and let me know how you are viewing the table?

Comment: i used the database browser plugin in Android Studio to check my database for values.
i first go to device monitor to look for the database file (in data/data/(appname)/database

the i just load the file into the database Browser plugin

Comment: maybe try not dropping the table in onUpgrade method

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is with whatever method you are using to come to the conclusion that leads you to say

> whenever I open up the database, it is always empty!

That is copying you code as supplied and then adding **MainActivity.java** as per :-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    userDatabase myDb;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        myDb = new userDatabase(this);

        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(
                myDb.getWritableDatabase()
                        .query(userDatabase.TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null)
        );

        Account a = myDb.login("Fred","password");
        Log.d(
                "ACCOUNTINFO",
                "Username = " + a.getUsername() +
                        " Email = " + a.getEmail() +
                        " Password = " + a.getPassword() +
                        " ID=" + String.valueOf(a.getId())
        );
    }
}
```

i.e. literally dumping the cursor after registering using :-

- username as **Fred**
- email as **fred@fredmail.com**
- password as **password**
- confirm password as **password**

The output in the log is :-

```
2019-06-17 22:20:14.653 15017-15017/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@1b21f
2019-06-17 22:20:14.653 15017-15017/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out: 0 {
2019-06-17 22:20:14.653 15017-15017/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out:    ID=1
2019-06-17 22:20:14.653 15017-15017/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out:    USERNAME=Fred
2019-06-17 22:20:14.654 15017-15017/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out:    PASSWORD=password
2019-06-17 22:20:14.654 15017-15017/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out:    EMAIL=fred@fredmail.com
2019-06-17 22:20:14.654 15017-15017/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out: }
2019-06-17 22:20:14.654 15017-15017/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out: <<<<<
2019-06-17 22:20:14.656 15017-15017/aso.so56626957signin D/ACCOUNTINFO: Username = Fred Email = password Password = fred@fredmail.com ID=1
```

The conclusion being that all the above code is appears to be working. You may wish to try the above code in your MainActivity.java.

However, you may notice that the password and email are swapped. This is due to the hard coded offsets being swapped. It is recommenede to not use hard coded offsets to get data from a Cursor, but to instead obtain the offset according to the column name.

It is also recommended to not hard code column names but use the constants instead and to also use the **query** method rather than the **rawQuery** method (when possible)

As such it is suggested that you change :-

```
public Account login(String username, String password) {
    Account account = null;
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME +
                        " where username = ? and password = ?",
                new String[]{username, password});

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            account = new Account();
            account.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            account.setUsername(cursor.getString(1));
            account.setEmail(cursor.getString(2));
            account.setPassword(cursor.getString(3));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        account = null;
    }
    return account;
}
```

to :-

```
public Account login(String username, String password) {
    Account account = null;
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                COL_USERNAME + "=? AND " + COL_PASSWORD + "=?",
                new String[]{username,password},
                null,null,null
        );
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            account = new Account();
            account.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_ID)));
            account.setUsername(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_USERNAME)));
            account.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_EMAIL)));
            account.setPassword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_PASSWORD)));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        account = null;
    }
    return account;
}
```

And likewise use :-

```
public Account checkUsername(String username) {
    Account account = null;
    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.query(
                TABLE_NAME,
                null,
                COL_USERNAME + "=?",
                new String[]{username},
                null,null,null
        );
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            account = new Account();
            account.setId(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_ID)));
            account.setUsername(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_USERNAME)));
            account.setEmail(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_EMAIL)));
            account.setPassword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COL_PASSWORD)));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        account = null;
    }
    return account;
}
```

This then result in :-

```
2019-06-17 22:37:08.273 15361-15361/aso.so56626957signin D/ACCOUNTINFO: Username = Fred Email = fred@fredmail.com Password = password ID=1
```

## Additional re comment

> im going to include my main activity in the post too

In short this makes little difference to the answer, the code works. So it is whatever makes you say

> whenever I open up the database, it is always empty!

That is the issue.

- Note after commenting out the line //intent.putExtra("Account", account);

You can prove this to be the case by amending the handling of the login in the **onCLick** method of MainActivity as per :-

@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

```
    if (v.getId()==R.id.buttonSignUp) {
        Intent intent  = new Intent(
                MainActivity.this,
                SignUp.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    else if (v.getId()==R.id.buttonLecturerLogin) {
        userDatabase userDatabase = new userDatabase(getApplicationContext());
        String username = editLoginUsername.getText().toString();
        String password = editLoginPassword.getText().toString();
        Account account = userDatabase.login(username, password);

        if (account == null) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());
            builder.setTitle("Error");
            builder.setMessage("Invalid Account");
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int which) {
                    dialogInterface.cancel();
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Lecturer.class);
            //intent.putExtra("Account", account);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    else if (v.getId()==R.id.buttonStudentLogin) {


        userDatabase myDb = new userDatabase(v.getContext()); //<<<<<<<<<< ADDED
        //Extract all users and dump them to the log
        DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(
                myDb.getWritableDatabase()
                        .query(userDatabase.TABLE_NAME,null,null,null,null,null,null)
        );
        //LOGIN ATTEMPT
        Account a = myDb.login(editLoginUsername.getText().toString(),editLoginPassword.getText().toString()); //<<<<<<<<<< attempt to login is here
        String loginresult = "Failed"; // Default value
        if (a != null) {
            loginresult = "Worked."; // value set to worked if the login worked
        }
        Log.d("LOGINRESULT","The attempt to login " + loginresult); //<<<<<<< write result of the login attempt to the log
        //code for when button is pressed, checks database then redirects accordingly
    }
}
```

Using the same username **Fred** and password **password** and then clicking on the Student Login button you will get :-

```
06-18 07:09:24.314 1881-1881/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@49e1d9f
06-18 07:09:24.314 1881-1881/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out: 0 {
06-18 07:09:24.314 1881-1881/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out:    ID=1
06-18 07:09:24.314 1881-1881/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out:    USERNAME=Fred
06-18 07:09:24.314 1881-1881/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out:    PASSWORD=password
06-18 07:09:24.314 1881-1881/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out:    EMAIL=fred@fredmail.com
06-18 07:09:24.314 1881-1881/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out: }
06-18 07:09:24.314 1881-1881/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out: <<<<<
06-18 07:09:24.314 1881-1881/aso.so56626957signin D/LOGINRESULT: The attempt to login Worked.
```

Trying the student login with other credentials would result in :-

```
06-18 07:09:34.264 1881-1881/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@6bcb36d
06-18 07:09:34.264 1881-1881/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out: 0 {
06-18 07:09:34.264 1881-1881/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out:    ID=1
06-18 07:09:34.264 1881-1881/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out:    USERNAME=Fred
06-18 07:09:34.264 1881-1881/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out:    PASSWORD=password
06-18 07:09:34.264 1881-1881/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out:    EMAIL=fred@fredmail.com
06-18 07:09:34.264 1881-1881/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out: }
06-18 07:09:34.264 1881-1881/aso.so56626957signin I/System.out: <<<<<
06-18 07:09:34.265 1881-1881/aso.so56626957signin D/LOGINRESULT: The attempt to login Failed
```

i.e. the first shows that there is data

Comment: oh my. i am really new in this so i really appreciate all the help i can get.
im going to include my main activity in the post too